# Rails project: why is my javascript file being ignored?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

[Update below: I figured out the problem]

My Rails project has a file called `assets/javascripts/presidents.js`. But it appears this file is not being called. I stuck a `console.log` in there and confirmed it's not doing anything:

```
$(function() {
  console.log("Testing");
  $.getJSON('', function(data){
    index = 3;
    chart(data);
    $("select").change(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      index = parseInt($("#chart").val()) + 2
      $("svg").remove();
      $(".d3-tip").remove();
      $("#chronological").prop("checked", true);
      chart(data);
    });
  });

});
```

The `config/initializers/assets.rb` file *does* mention the `presidents.js` file:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['presidents.js', 'presidents.scss', 'index.js', 'd3-tooltips.js']`

I know that the `index.html.erb` is being called, because the HTML shows up when I run the server. But my javascript is being ignored.

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/index.json`, my json data is there.

What am I missing here?

[Update: I figured out how to fix the problem. I added this to my `assets/javascripts/application.js` file before `//=require turbolinks`:

`//= require jquery`

`//= require jquery_ujs`

The second line might not be necessary in my version of Rails but the first line definitely is.]

Comment: In most cases you do not need to add specific js or scss files to the precompilation step here, as Asset Pipeline takes care of it. What does your assets/javascript/application.js look like?

Comment: That file is empty. Just the default commented-out text. But it includes this - "// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement."

Comment: So I copied my presidents.js code into application.js and it does appear to be hitting it. But in my original version of the app, I didn't need to do that, so I'm not still not sure why that file's being ignored.

Comment: Should 'assets/javascripts/presidents.js' be renamed with no 's' in 'javascripts' as 'assets/javascript/presidents.js' ?

Comment: No, 'javascripts' with an 's' is correct. It's part of the default file structure of Rails. And ```application.js``` and ```presidents.js``` are both in that same folder at any rate.

Comment: If you have the last line in application.js as    //= require_tree .      it should pull in presidents.js for you, no need to put it in application.js. As long as presidents.js is in the same folder as application.js

Comment: Yes, the last line is ```//= require_tree . ``` but it still doesn't pull in the presidents.js file.

Comment: I fixed it. See main text.